# Manage elements of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a jquery called maphilight.

I use this method to highligh a specific map of a image.

```
$('.key').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
    data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
    $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
});
```

I'm using 3 different class (key, alpha and control). and this method that i posted on the top highlight individual keys. Now i want to highlight a group of keys with the class alpha and control (all maps are key class).

I was using this one

```
$('#balpha').click(function(e) {            
    $('.alpha').each(function(e) {              
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
        data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
        $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    });
});
```

But doesn't do anything, any tips?

Comment: A little formatting never hurts

Comment: @Huangism: Apparantly neither does a little more formatting :)

Comment: ye just edited it sorry.

Comment: you are probably getting an error. Check your console (hit f12). You call `e.preventDefault` but `e` at that point is the index of the each function and won't have a method called `preventDefault`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage elements with the same class in a Jquery method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661430/how-to-manage-elements-with-the-same-class-in-a-jquery-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you set same variable for two function. It must causes the problem.

```
$('#balpha').click(function(event) {            
    $('.alpha').each(function(e) {              
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
        data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
        $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I will try to be more specific.

```
    $('.key').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
        data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
        $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    });
```

This method change a single part of my mapped image.

And I want to change some areas in the same time with a button.

If I change the method for this one.

```
    $('·balpha').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $('.alpha').mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
        data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
        $('.alpha').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    });
```

It change multiple areas of my map, but then when I try to change them individually, they work as one area with multiple areas inside. [Image of the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiHAW.png)

PD: I tried to change the variables, but then nothing happens.